# How to prove that : $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n\frac{k^8}{(a+(k+b)^2)^4}=1$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-sum

I am just having fun with this question: 
Is this true that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n\frac{k^8}{(a+(k+b)^2)^4}=1$?

I thought to change this to an integral, namely that $$S_n=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{1/n}^1\frac{x^8}{(\frac{a}{n^2}+(x+\frac{b}{n})^2)^4}dx=1$$

Some how this does not feel alright, but would be happy if you could give me a hint whether on whether this is alright. I will also be very thankful for any other hint, or other solutions. Many thanks.

Comment: Feels right to me !

Comment: If you could somehow show the limit to be independent of $a$ and $b$, we could just take $a=b=0$ and sum is trivial.

Comment: If $a_k \to \alpha$, then $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \to \alpha.$$

Comment: Many thanks! It makes sense.